# Xero API UK leaveTypeID

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to use the following code to update start and end dates of leave (UK payroll)

{
"leaveTypeID": "b8b4b3e2-1f1b-442b-8af7-4bb78e9e40e6",
"description": "Test",
"startDate": "2023-11-26",
"endDate": "2023-12-12",
"periods": [
{
"periodStartDate": "2023-11-20T00:00:00",
"periodEndDate": "2023-11-26T00:00:00",
"numberOfUnits": 0,
"periodStatus": "Approved"
} {
"periodStartDate": "2023-11-27T00:00:00",
"periodEndDate": "2023-12-03T00:00:00",
"numberOfUnits": 5,
"periodStatus": "Approved"
} {
"periodStartDate": "2023-12-04T00:00:00",
"periodEndDate": "2023-12-10T00:00:00",
"numberOfUnits": 5,
"periodStatus": "Approved"
} {
"periodStartDate": "2023-12-11T00:00:00",
"periodEndDate": "2023-12-17T00:00:00",
"numberOfUnits": 2,
"periodStatus": "Approved"
}
]
}

I get 400 code with the error "Leave type id is not provided or in invalid format"

I cant see what is wrong with the format and I have used the GET leaveTypes function to confirm that the leaveTypeID is correct.

Am I missing something?  Or is there an error/bug?